# Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 800a138f

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blob, internet-explorer-11

I am getting following error in IE 11 -

> Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 800a138f.

Code is as follows -

```
File = function(k, j, i) {
    var e = new Blob(k, i);
    e.name = j;
    e.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    return e;
}
```

Not sure what is going wrong. I do not see any other erros in the console. Just some subsequent error saying cannot find property of null (since above file is null).

Any idea whats wrong with above piece of code. Works fine with chrome and firefox?

EDIT : 
The entire logic is -

```
                try {
                    new File([], "")
                } catch (g) {
                    console.log(g);
                    File = function(k, j, i) {
                        var e = new Blob(k, i);
                        e.name = j;
                        e.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
                        return e;
                    }
                }
```

I added log to see why it goes to catch and I see following -

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this action
```

Comment: That code produces no error for me - however, *when called without a third argument* it does ..how are you calling that function (note: you're overwriting a native `File` object, is that your intent?)

Comment: @JaromandaX updated the question with more code and exception I see. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: as my comment said, IE11 fails if you do not supply the third argument (which is used in the Blob constructor) - suggest `application/octet-stream`

Comment: @JaromandaX it would be great if you could provide some more info around the arguments accespted by Blob. I am faitly new to this. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation that says the second argument is mandatory in IE11 - all I can do is deduce from the evidence that it is

Comment: got similar issue, the solution was to not pass in undefined `new Blob(k, i || {})`

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't have an IE under the hands to test it, I would say it's because `window.File` does exist on this browser and that you can't override this property.

Indeed, even though you are not able to call the File constructor from your script in this browser, the File constructor existed there, so e.g what you get in an `input[type='file']` is an instance of `File`.

```js
console.log(typeof window.File === "function" && 'File already exists');
inp.onchange = function() {
  if(inp.files[0] instanceof File) {
    console.log("yep, that's a File");
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
```

#### So they made this property non-writable, what now?

Well, that depends on what you wanted to do with this File anyway.
There is currently a very limited number of use cases for such an object:

- Avoid to set the third param `filename` to `FormData.append('fieldName', blob, filename)`,
- and **only in chrome**, append the File to a FileList through `DataTransfer.items.add()` method.

Everything else you could have done with this File, will be done the same with a Blob, and these two methods won't be accessible to your fakeFile anyway.

---

But if you really want to do it, then I guess that simply choosing an other name for your function will make IE happy:

```js
// Beware, untested code below
(function() {
  var blob = new Blob(['foo'], {
      type: 'text/plain'
    }),
    file;
  try {
    file = new File([blob], 'foo.txt');
    if (file.name !== 'foo.txt' || !file.lastModifiedDate || !file.type === 'text/plain') {
      throw new Error('invalid');
    }
    window.MyFile = File;
  } catch (e) {
    window.MyFile = function(k, j, i) {
      var e = new Blob(k, i);
      e.name = j;
      e.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
      return e;
    };
  }
})();

var file = new MyFile([new Blob(['bar'], {
  type: 'text/plain'
})], 'mytext.txt');
console.log(file);
```